# Problems with Octave font and size changes

Tags: fonts, octave

I would like help with a problem that I am having in Octave 3.6.4 on Ubuntu 13.04.

I have looked up a number of ways to change the font size and/or the font of the legend, the title, or the axes of a plot; and I have found that the code that I find does not work.  I have tried copying in a number of snippets of code meant to change the size of text or font, and I haven't been able to change them.

The font that Octave shows when outputting a graph is a normal fixed-width font.

Can anyone help me?  I have tried things such as...

```
xlabel('x-title', 'FontSize', 20)
```

or

```
xlabel('x-title', 'FontName', 'Vera')
```

or

```
foo = xlabel('x-title')
set(foo, 'FontSize', 20)
```

or

```
foo = xlabel('x-title)
set(foo, 'FontName', 'Vera')
```

And none change the font.

Comment: that's very weird. Those snippets work fine on my system which is running the same version of Octave. If you start Octave from the command line with `octave --norc`, and then enter `pkg unload all; plot (0:10); xlabel ("label", "fontsize", 50)` does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem with Octave 3.6.4 and Ubuntu 12.04. If you don't care how the figure looks in Octave but just how it looks when outputted to file, then this should work:

```
plot(1:10);
xlabel("example");ylabel("example");title("example");
fontsize=20;
set([gca; findall(gca, 'Type','text')], 'FontSize', fontsize);
set([gca; findall(gca, 'Type','line')], 'linewidth', 3);
hx=legend('example');set(hx, "fontsize", fontsize)
saveas(1, "presentation.jpg");
```